# How to insert value into an HTML form using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a form in a file named signup.php like this,

```
<form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username..."><br><br>
<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email..."><br><br>                  
<input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password..."><br><br>
<input type="password" name="repeatPwd" placeholder="Repeat Password..."><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="btnSignup" value="Signup">
</form>
```

Then I have this if statement in the signup.inc.php file.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-z0-9]*$/", $username)) {                           
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduid&mail=".$email);
    exit();
}
```

That is if the user enter invalid username, then the user will be route back to the signup page, and I get an error message in the address bar, now I want to get the email from the address bar which the user entered, I make an if statement back in the signup.php file like this,

```
if ($_GET['error'] == "invaliduid") {
    echo "Invalid username."; 
    $email = $_GET['mail'];
}
```

Now I want to fill the original form

```
<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email...">
```

And put the email from `$_GET['mail']` and put it in the value portion of the form, but I am stuck on how to do this.
The program should work like this, if the user entered proper mail and an invalid username then the user route back to the signup page with the message invalid username, and email field should be populated with the email which he already entered.

Comment: Just check if the parameter is set, and if so, output it as content of the value attribute of the field. (Don’t forget to apply proper, context aware escaping.)

Comment: You POST your form, but you're using $_GET. You Should be using $_POST. If you send your visitor to a new form page, you will need to recreate the form if when there is an error. Instead you should use the same form page, and then you can use your $_POST in the input values. If there are no errors, then you can handle the form submission on the same script/page.

Comment: @misorude Your first point shouldn't matter (I think..) if he posts to a page that redirects him with new routing parameters that he can process from the url.

Comment: @Jonast92 yeah, I overlooked the redirect part at first.

Comment: There's a header that redirects if there's an error back to the form. And it includes get parameters -- so it is possible... @Hassan Javed use $_GET['mail'] as your value for the email input field.

Comment: @JeffVdovjak how to insert $_GET['mail'] as a value for my form? its not in the same php tags? its giving me error        Undefined index: mail

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, what you're looking for is simply this:

```
<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email..." value="<?= htmlspecialchars($email) ?>">
```

(which is a less ugly way to write the following:)

```
<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email..." value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>">
```

Comment: Good call. Edited. I kinda just explained the basic idea without fully considering the right way to do things.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Short "echo" opening tags (`<?=`) cannot be turned off on any supported PHP version. Only the full short tag, `<?` can (and should be!) turned off.

Comment: Woops, my mistake. :(

Comment: How does it invite XSS to the site as it is the value for an input field. A visitor could directly type the value into the input field. The XSS would occur on the processing of the submit form (and presumably an insert/update to the database) -- not on the setting of an input field on the client-side. You can htmlspecialchar it -- but then the visitor can just re-type whatever XSS they were trying.

Comment: @JeffVdovjak The value comes from GET, so you could give someone a link with malicious code in the GET and they would get a hacked website.

Comment: @Dharma This code would not protect the database/site at all. This would "protect" the site from outputting content they didn't want into an input field. The htmlspecialchars would have to be on the signup.inc.php not the signup.php. Submitting XSS in this input field would still work (it would just clean it if there was an error, and then output a clean text value). It would prevent someone from inadvertently submitting XSS... but wouldn't stop someone from purposely submitting XSS.

Comment: @JeffVdovjak I don't know what you are talking about. XSS has nothing to do with database. XSS is to protect the HTML/JavaScript from malicious client-side code.

Comment: @Dharman sorry -- early morning brain-fart --- I was thinking SQL injection. Because there's nothing present in the code thus far that makes me think "secure"

Comment: @ooa this is not working for me.     <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email..." value="<?= htmlspecialchars($email) ?>">

Comment: @HassanJaved You need to expand on that sentence. Did you add `value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET['mail']) ?>"`

Comment: yes i did <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email..." value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>"><br><br>

Answer (score 0):

This here is working as intended:

```
<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email..." value="<?php echo(isset($email))?$email:'';?>">
```

Comment: @HassanJaved That's the ternary operator. If the statement is true it outputs the $email, otherwise it outputs ''.